# issues making default collection for solr

Tags: solr, geonetwork

I am trying to install solr so that my data catalog could use it. To do so, I used these steps which are mentioned on the documentation of my data portal:

```
cd solr/solr-config
wget http://apache.crihan.fr/dist/lucene/solr/6.0.0/solr-6.0.0.tgz
tar xvfz solr-6.0.0.tgz
solr-6.0.0/bin/solr start -c -p 8984
solr-6.0.0/bin/solr create -p 8984 -c catalog_srv -d src/main/solr-cores/catalog
```

accourding to these instructions I made a directory /opt/solr/solr-config the downloaded and unziped solr, and started it on port 8984. Now I don't understand how does the last command works. what should be the second path  src/main/solr-cores/catalog? I thought I should generatet the directories src, main solr-cores and catalog inside my solr-config directory and then run this command. but I got errors that solrconfig.xml could not be found. after adding solrconfig.xml to /opt/solr/solr-config/src/main/solr-cores/catalog, now I get an error:

```
ERROR: Failed to create collection 'catalog_srv' due to: {127.0.1.1:8984_solr=org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException:Error from server at http://127.0.1.1:8984/solr: Error CREATEing SolrCore 'catalog_srv_shard1_replica1': Unable to create core [catalog_srv_shard1_replica1] Caused by: Can't find resource 'schema.xml' in classpath or '/configs/catalog_srv', cwd=/opt/solr/solr-config/solr-6.6.0/server}
```

what is schema.xml? is it something about data of my data portal? could you please explain the issue and how should I determine the path src/main/solr-cores/catalog to avoid these errors? what does exactly a default collection of solr do?

More info: my data portal is an opensource software called geonetwork and the documentation about solr is here: http://geonetwork-opensource.org/manuals/trunk/eng/users/maintainer-guide/installing/installing-solr.html?highlight=solr

Comment: `-d` is the location of the configuration for the collection you're creating. This should be included in one of the repositories from geonetwork.

Comment: So if I am not misunderstood, you mean this location should not be arbitrary? It should be a specific directory in geonetwork repository?

Comment: Yes, the directory should contain geonetworks / geoservers Solr configuration for the collection.

Comment: I got your point, Thank you so much.

Comment: If you are using an external solr you will need this folder to run the last command you wrote: https://github.com/geonetwork/core-geonetwork/tree/solr/solr/solr-config/src/main/solr-cores/catalog and point the `-d` argument to it.